# Generate a Single Diff from multiple changelists from different files and folders

Tags: diff, perforce, review-board

Is it possible in perforce, or regular diff or p4v, to generate a single diff which contains changes from multiple changelists? We have about 10 changelists that are **checked in** and we need a single diff for and they include changes across different files and folders.

We would like to post the diff on reviewboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
p4 diff2 -u //path/to/files/...@change1 //path/to/files/...@change2
```

Where change1 is the changelist right **before** the first changelist you're interested in, and change2 is the last changelist you're interested in.

If that wasn't precisely what you were interested in, perhaps you can post more details about how close it was to the answer you were hoping for, and what parts of the output didn't quite match what you needed.